# Question About Discrete Probability Space ,Discrete And Continuous Random Variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Omega$ Be any non empty set and $D\subseteq \Omega$ be any countable subset. Let $p:D\to [0,1]$ such that $$\sum\limits_{x_{i}\in D}p(xi)=1$$.

Now ,Define $P:2^{\Omega}\to [0,1]$ $~$ as for any $A\in 2^{\Omega}$ $$P(A)=\sum\limits_{x_{i}\in A}p(xi)$$.

Then $P(\phi)=0$ and using Thoerems about series we can prove countable additivity.And here all things can be done without concerning about cardinality of $\Omega$.so $(\Omega,2^{\Omega},P)$ becomes probability space .specially **Discrete Probability space**.

> (1)  If it is the case then why most of texts defined discrete space given  $\Omega$ is **countable**?

Now let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ Be  probability space and $X:\Omega \to \Bbb R$ be random variable .

Certainly if $X(\Omega)=\left\{t\in \Bbb R : t=X(\omega) ,\text{for some} ~ \omega \in X \right \}$ is countable then $X$ is discrete random variable. For converse we can define random variable $X$ such that $X(\Omega)$ contain some uncountable set $U\in B(\Bbb R)$ ,but $P(X\in U)=0$ ,but I am not able to find any example of such random variable .

> $(2)$ So is there any discrete random variable with uncountable range?

Simillary texts Roughly write $X$ is continuous random variable if it takes values in uncountable set.

Now if we use **$X$ is said to be continuous random variable if its CDF is continuous function** , then is it true that

> $X$ is continuous random variable iff $X(\Omega)$ is uncountable?

Comment: (1) Because $P(\Omega \setminus D) = 0.$ (2) Yes, consider $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ be the real line with the Borel sets and let $P$ be the discrete measure with values $\frac{1}{2}$ both at zero and at one. Then let $X$ be the identity random variable. Then $X$ is discrete, $X(\mathbf{R}) = \mathbf{R}$ and the distribution of $X$ is the function $t \mapsto 0$ on $(-\infty,0),$ $t \mapsto \frac{1}{2}$ on $[0, 1)$ and $t \mapsto 1$ on $[1, \infty).$ Obviously, this also answers your last question with a "No."

Comment: @WilliamM. Here you say$ P(\Omega \setminus D) = 0$. You mean " elements of $\Omega \setminus D$ are **extra**.or in some sense they will not affect further  thoery . ?

Comment: $\Omega \setminus D$ has probability zero. So, in that sense they are extra.

Comment: Yes got it .  From your example $X(\Omega) $ countable $\Rightarrow$ $X$ Discrete. converse not necessary .$X$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $X(\Omega) $ uncountable. converse not necessary .    Thank You